# Quadratic Recurrence Relations

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Does anyone know combinatoric methods to get solutions to quadratic recurrences? An example of what I'm looking for:

$$F_{n+1} = 3F_n^2-2F_n$$

under the initial condition $F_0 =2, F_1 = 8$.

Much more tricky than a linear recurrence.

Comment: I think generating functions could do it. Not sure if it makes since though. $F_1 \ne 3F_0^2-2F_0$.

Comment: Fixed, I wasn't able to do it with generating functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A linear substitution can get rid of the linear term on the right, leaving only the quadratic term and a constant term. Here, if we let $G_n = 3F_n - 1$, then the recurrence relation turns into
$$
    \frac{G_{n+1}+1}{3} = 3 \left(\frac{G_n + 1}{3}\right)^2 - 2 \left(\frac{G_n+1}{3}\right)
$$
which simplifies to $G_{n+1} = G_n^2 - 2$. We might hope that this is easier to deal with...

---

...but I don't actually know how to solve a general recurrence of this type. In this case, we are lucky that the constant is a $2$, because a general solution to *this* recurrence relation is $G_n = \alpha^{2^n} + \alpha^{-2^n}$; this recurrence comes up in applications such as the Lucas-Lehmer test for primality.  We can check that
$$
   \left(\alpha^{2^n} + \alpha^{-2^n}\right)^2 - 2 = (\alpha^{2^{n+1}} + 2 + \alpha^{-2^{n+1}}) - 2 = \alpha^{2^{n+1}} + \alpha^{-2^{n+1}}.
$$
How do we choose $\alpha$? To satisfy the initial condition $\alpha + \frac1\alpha = G_0$.

Here, we have $G_0 = 3F_0 - 1 = 5$. This means $\alpha + \frac1\alpha = 5$, so $\alpha = \frac{5 \pm \sqrt{21}}{2}$. We can choose either root, because the other root is the reciprocal, getting $$G_n = \left(\frac{5+\sqrt{21}}{2}\right)^{2^n} + \left(\frac{5-\sqrt{21}}{2}\right)^{2^n}$$ with $F_n = \frac{G_n + 1}{3}$. The first few values of $G_n$ we get from this formula are $5, 23, 527, 277727, \dots$, giving us $2, 8, 176, 92576, \dots$ for $F_n$.

Comment: WolframAlpha offers the following alternative solution: $$F_n=2\cos[2^{n-1} \cos^{-1}(23/2)]$$ The equivalence with the solution here presumably follows from Euler’s formula.

Comment: Yes, though I would prefer to write that expression as $2 \cosh[2^{n-1} \cosh^{-1}(23/2)]$. The two are equivalent, but $\cos^{-1}(23/2)$ isn't the "usual" kind of arccosine, because $23/2 \notin [-1,1]$.

Comment: Agreed. To further connect the two, one can check that $$\frac{1}{2}\cosh^{-1}\frac{23}{2}=\ln\left(\frac{5+\sqrt{21}}{2}\right)=-\ln\left(\frac{5-\sqrt{21}}{2}\right)$$ (Or at least, WolframAlpha verifies this.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov You might be interested in the alternative solution that I posted in the Answers.

Answer (score 1):

This alternative solution is too long for a comment, so I'm posting it as an answer.

In my (admittedly, limited) experience, the only known closed form solution to a quadratic recurrence is for $a_n=a_{n-1}^2-2$. And therefore, given a quadratic recurrence to solve, the first thing to do is to try to get it into that form. As was masterfully done by Misha Lavrov. The solution to this recurrence is based on the identity $\cos 2\alpha=2\cos^2\alpha-1$, or similarly for $\cosh2\alpha$.

However, I came across another solution that you might find interesting. This method *linearizes* the recurrence as follows:

$$
a_n=a_{n-1}^2-2\\
a_n=b_n+\frac{1}{b_n}\\
b_n+\frac{1}{b_n}=\bigg(b_{n-1}+\frac{1}{b_{n-1}} \bigg)^2-2=b_{n-1}^2+\frac{1}{b_{n-1}^2}\\
b_n-b_{n-1}^2=\frac{1}{b_{n-1}^2}-\frac{1}{b_n}=\frac{b_n-b_{n-1}^2}{b_nb_{n-1}^2}\\
b_nb_{n-1}^2=1\\
\ln(b_nb_{n-1}^2)=0\\
g_n=\ln(b_n)\\
g_n=-2g_{n-1}\\
g_n=(-2)^ng_0\\
b_n=b_0e^{(-2)^n}\\
a_n=b_n+\frac{1}{b_n}\\
a_0=b_0+\frac{1}{b_0}\\
b_0=\frac{a_0\pm\sqrt{a_0^2-4}}{2}
$$

And so on. The results are the same as the $\cos,\cosh$ solutions, albeit in exponential form.